# problema em reconhecer href como link

Tags: php, html, link

Estou com um problema que meu `href` não esta reconhecendo o link vindo do banco de dados.

Por exemplo se eu colocar www.facebook.com no banco de dados, quando eu chamo ele dentro do `href` ele me trás `href="localhost/projeto/www.facebook.com"`, porem se eu pegar o link do facebook https://www.facebook.com/ e colocar no banco de dados quando eu chamar no `href` ele me retorna assim `href="https://www.facebook.com/"` ou seja ele me retorna o link correto.
alguem sabe o que tenho que fazer para o `href` reconhecer o www.facebook.com como um link?

Comment: Acho que seu problema é a falta do protocolo `http://`, `https://` na frente do link provavelmente seu link esta assim `<a href='facebook.com'>` deveria estar `<a href='https://facebook.com'>`

Comment: então mas ai e que está não sou eu quem vou administrar isso não tenho como saber se a pessoa que vai administrar vai usar o protocolo, por que seria simples só colocar o `https://` antes do conteúdo que ela digitar.

Comment: cabe ao programador tratar os dados enviado via input e definir se o que o usuário digitou está correto! o problema provavelmente é o que o @IcaroMartins mencionou, eu tentaria tratar esse input para não deixar salvar a url sem http!

Comment: Acho que seria bom você tratar isso do lado do servidor, verificando se o usuário vai digitar http ou não na hora de salvar.

Comment: Sabendo que vai ser um link, na leitura dos dados (antes de colocar o `a href`) voce pode remover o `http://` ou `https://` e colocar somente o `//` como no exemplo `<a href="//facebook.com">` se eu não estou enganado isso deve funciona para `a href` tambem, ele vai selecionar o protocolo automaticamente baseado na pagina atual

Comment: entendi nao sabia que somente o `//` funcionava eu sempre achei que deveria especificar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ideal e você tratar antes de inserir em sua base de dados, porem se você sabe que sempre sera um link externo você pode remover o `http://` e `https://` quando tiver, e usar o `//` como mostrado no exemplo abaixo. Ele vai se comportar de forma automatica baseado na pagina atual, ou seja, se você estiver sobre o protocolo `http://` ele vai usar `http://` se voce estiver sobre o protocolo `https://` ele vai utilizar `https://`.

```html
<a href='//facebook.com' target='_blank'>Facebook</a>
```

> Possível problema: Se voce estiver sobe o protocolo `https://` pode ser que a pagina destino não tenha isso implementado.

Outra solução e você sempre remover `http://` e `https://` e colocar por padrão o  `http://`.

Comment: se não for somente com link externo isso da certo também não?

Comment: Só se o link tiver o `dominio` exemplo `//meusite.com/pagina2.html`

Comment: então ta certo já fiz aqui já testei também ta funcionando